# React cambio de nombre al hacer click. state

Tags: reactjs

Cómo hacer para al hacer click en un botón por ejemplo, me cambie el nombre que tengo en el state. adjunto código(hay cosas de mas como por ejemplo el contador que si me funciona)

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import estilos from '../css/estilos.css'


class Componente extends Component{

    constructor(props){
        super(props)
        this.state = {
          count : 0,
          nombre : "Tiago"
        }
      }
      cnombre = (e) => {
          e.preventDefault(e)
          this.setState((prevState)=>{
              return{
                   nombre : prevState.nombre = "Mariano"

              }
          })
      }

      sumar = (e) =>{
        e.preventDefault()
        this.setState(function(prevState){
            return{
                count : prevState.count + 1
              }     
        })    
      }

      sumar2 = (e) =>{
          e.preventDefault()
          this.setState((prevState)=>{
              return{
                  count : prevState.count + 2
              }
          })
      }

      restar = (e) =>{
        e.preventDefault()
        this.setState((prevState)=>{
            if(prevState.count >= 1){
                return{
                    count : prevState.count - 1
                }
            }    
        })
      }

      resetear = (e) =>{
          e.preventDefault()
          this.setState({count:0})
      }



    render(){

    return(
        <div>

        <a href="#" onClick = {this.sumar} className = "sumar"> Sumar</a>
        <a href="#" onClick = {this.restar} className = "restar"> Restar</a>
        <a href="#" onClick = {this.resetear} className = "reset"> Resetear</a>
        <a href="#" onClick = {this.sumar2} className = "reset"> Sumar de a dos</a>
        <p onClick = {this.cnombre}>Tiago</p>
        <button onClick = {this.cnombre}>Cambiar</button>
          {this.state.count}

        </div>




    )



}



}

export default Componente
```

Comment: Tiago, como sabes que el __state__ no te está cambiando?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

todo el tiempo te ha estado funcionando, lo que pasa es que no estás visualizando el cambio porque no estás utilizando el nombre del estado en ningún lugar. Si cambias la implementación del método `render` por esta:

```
render() {
    return(
        <div>
            <a href="#" onClick = {this.sumar} className = "sumar"> Sumar</a>
            <a href="#" onClick = {this.restar} className = "restar"> Restar</a>
            <a href="#" onClick = {this.resetear} className = "reset"> Resetear</a>
            <a href="#" onClick = {this.sumar2} className = "reset"> Sumar de a dos</a>

            {/* Aqui esta el cambio: Tiago => {this.state.nombre} */}
            <p onClick = {this.cnombre}>{this.state.nombre}</p>

            <button onClick = {this.cnombre}>Cambiar</button>
            {this.state.count}
        </div>
    )
}
```

Espero que funcione y si es así marca esta como la respuesta correcta (importante), sino, déjame saber que fue mal.

Comment: Tiago, si esta respuesta te funcionó, busca como marcarla como la respuesta correcta, por favor. Gracias!!

Comment: hola josue. lo que me dijiste me menciono. muchas gracias. no me deja valorar la respuesta porque aun no tengo la calificacion que me permita hacer este tipo de valoraciones. gracias igual

Comment: Tiago, me referia a que la marques como **respuesta aceptada**, deberia ser posible aunq no tengas una calificación alta, ya q es de las cosas basicas q todo usuario puede hacer, al igual q el hecho de poder hacer una pregunta. Las preguntas se marcan como **aceptadas** marcando la palomita gris al costado de la respuesta en cuestion. Al aceptarla, se tornara verde. Intentalo, por favor.

Comment: ahi esta. ya entendi lo que quisiste decir. saludos